# MvcContrib TestHelpers broken in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mvccontrib

I have just upgraded my project to MVC3 using Razor.  The project includes MvcContrib and I am using the MvcContrib.TestHelper methods for testing redirects, view rendering, etc.  When I run the project, all views and redirects are working fine, but now all of my unit tests that use these helper methods are failing.  Anyone know why this might be?  Is there an update to MvcContrib that I have to use?  I thought the stuff in MvcContrib would be incorporated into MVC3 anyway . . .

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And the anwser is, yes, you have to get the latest version of MvcContrib, it seems.  Got the most recent version and now everything is passing again.